# why module pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've read a lot of things about the **module** pattern.
Ok It brings structure, private method, etc... 
But with the code below I can get the same behavior without using it.

```
function Human()
{
  // private properties
  var _name='';
  var _age=0;


  // private methods
  function created()
  {
    console.log("Human "+_name+" called");
  };

  // public
  this.setName = function(name){
    _name=name;
    created(); 
  };

}


var h1 = new Human();

h1.setName("John");
```

So, what are the real advantage of a module pattern finally ?

Comment: I don't think you are implementing the pattern properly.  You'd use an IIFE (instantly invoked function expression) to implement your private methods.  Check out this blog post [http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) for a much more in depth look.

Comment: Indeed, this is not the "module pattern", and in my opinion this code does the same thing !?

Comment: The module pattern is about using an anonymous function to control variable scope (rather than dumping things into a global namespace). Your example is a variation of a module pattern (using a function constructor instead of an anonymous function), if you were dealing with more complex relationships or non-constructor functions, then it would be more relevant. check out: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: FYI: `this.setName` is not a public method. Public methods do not have access to private variables. It's considered a **privileged** method: it can be accessed publicly, but also has access to private variables. For more info, read Crockford's article: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: I would call it a public method. It's pointless to give a public method direct access to a property Java-setter-style but that doesn't make it not public, IMO. Public is about where you can access, not what it touches on the inside. I've never seen a need to add more layers of method-types than that to JS OOP and Crockford himself says he never really ended up using that style of class-emulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this example could help you to clarify the usefulness of the **Module Pattern**.

### Module Pattern

> The module pattern is widely used because it provides structure and helps organize
>   your code as it grows. Unlike other languages, JavaScript doesn’t have special syntax
>   for packages, but the module pattern provides the tools to create self-contained decoupled
>   pieces of code, which can be treated as black boxes of functionality and added,
>   replaced, or removed according to the (ever-changing) requirements of the software
>   you’re writing.

The module pattern is a combination of several patterns, namely:

- Namespaces
- Immediate functions
- Private and privileged members
- Declaring dependencies

The first step is setting up a namespace. Let’s use the **namespace()** function from earlier
in this chapter and start an example utility module that provides useful array methods:

```
MYAPP.namespace('MYAPP.utilities.array');
```

The next step is defining the module. The pattern uses an immediate function that will
provide private scope if privacy is needed. The immediate function returns an object - the actual module with its public interface, which will be available to the consumers of
the module:

```
 MYAPP.utilities.array = (function () {
    return {
    // todo...
    };
 }());
```

Next, let’s add some methods to the public interface:

```
MYAPP.utilities.array = (function () {
   return {
      inArray: function (needle, haystack) {
         // ...
      },
      isArray: function (a) {
         // ...
      }
   };
}());
```

Using the private scope provided by the immediate function, you can declare some
private properties and methods as needed. Right at the top of the immediate function
will also be the place to declare any dependencies your module might have. Following
the variable declarations, you can optionally place any one-off initialization code that
helps set up the module. The final result is an object returned by the immediate function
that contains the public API of your module:

```
MYAPP.namespace('MYAPP.utilities.array');
MYAPP.utilities.array = (function () {
   // dependencies
   var uobj = MYAPP.utilities.object,
       ulang = MYAPP.utilities.lang,
       // private properties
       array_string = "[object Array]",
       ops = Object.prototype.toString;
       // private methods
       // ...
       // end var
   // optionally one-time init procedures
   // ...
   // public API
   return {
      inArray: function (needle, haystack) {
         for (var i = 0, max = haystack.length; i < max; i += 1) {
            if (haystack[i] === needle) {
               return true;
            }
         }
      },
      isArray: function (a) {
         return ops.call(a) === array_string;
      }
      // ... more methods and properties
   };
}());
```

The module pattern is a widely used and highly recommended way to **organize** your
code, especially as it grows.

*“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov
(O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750*

Comment: Ok, but now If I change this.inArray: ... and this.isArray: ... and remove the return closure; what is the difference ? (except I'm not using a closure) I still have a public API no ?

Comment: Exposing crtical methods like inArray or isArray is sometime dangerous. Indeed somebody could change the method implementation in this way: 'this.isArray = null'. At opposite, if you implement inArray or isArray as private methods and return an object exposing them (in a public api) i.e.: return '{ IsArray: isArray };', your code will continue to work, since its critical functions are hidden to the programmer. :)
More info in the 'Revealing pattern' previously know as 'revealing module pattern'.

Comment: Mmhhh, May be a matter of choice finally. I've seen a lot of "Module Pattern vs Anonymous Constructor" on Google... Try benchmark too :  http://jsperf.com/module-pattern-vs-anonymous-constructor

Comment: @user278064 But the OP's approach wouldn't expose his private methods. I'm confused as to why people think this is the way to go for basic inheritable object factories. Furthermore, it's not so much "dangerous" unless you're working with hamfisted charlatans who have no place on a development team. It just makes your code easier to understand and refactor by making it clear what data an object is solely responsible and how it's meant to interact with external concerns. With JS you can't afford to think like a Java dev. It's not at all a protectionist language.

Comment: -1. You straight copied an example from a book clearly references code in *a previous chapter* which you do not supply.

Comment: You straight copied an example from a book clearly references code in a previous chapter which you do not supply.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why no one's answered this one properly. I can see potential for using auto-invoking functions in some kind of pattern meant to make private vars inheritable, but you're absolutely right.

There is no benefit to using the module pattern in place of a core language function constructor. It's the same exact language mechanic (closures) that allows the persistent internal vars to exist as non-accessible entities only with more code.

In JS a function constructor follows the same rules of scope as a fired function. Scope and closure is set at point of definition. The reason the internal var from a function constructor lives on is because the instance with methods defined inside the same constructor referencing that var lives on.

The only thing that changes is that you've eliminated the use of prototyped methods on the constructor and have to jury-rig your own inheritance mechanism for inherited methods.

Comment: This is the only answer by someone who has apparently read the question and tried to help the asker understand what he was asking about.

Comment: How does the Module Pattern make private vars inheritable ? Where is the inheritance ? Isn't everything just working because the methods of the returned object have closure over the enclosing function's scope ?

Comment: _"The only thing that changes is that you've eliminated the use of prototyped methods on the constructor and have to jury-rig your own inheritance mechanism for inherited methods"_. Wouldn't OP be able to just use `Foo.call(this)` to inherit the methods in the same way they would be able to inherit a parent's properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Huge JavaScript projects out there are getting built use module patterns, perhaps you have your own idea and want to make sure your code is easily readable and well structured. 
by learn a couple of patterns you could make your apps easier to build and to maintain.
 these patterns are used by the most JavaScript talented developers, for instance the folks build node js, JQuery, bootstrap, angular and others. 
Simple Example:

```
  function foo (){
    console.log("foobar");
};

foo();
```

> when we invoke this simple method, we will notice it’s accessible in global name space, and when we talking about large application this is a huge problem.

this is sometimes we refer to it as cluttering the global name space. 
The reason this is a problem is because so much is happening in the browser, you might load angular, bootstrap and Jquery in the browser, you might even have a few other javascript libraries.
Now if you have to navigate a bunch of variables that clutter the global name space, it could be quit a no sense. In fact it could be even a catastrophic if the variables you create share the same name as variables from another library. 
The most basic module pattern is going to solve this. To do this I describe my code in a self executing anonymous function, and now looks like this:
From this:

```
function foo (){
    console.log("foobar");
};

foo();
```

To this:

```
(function(){function foo (){
    console.log("foobar");
};

foo();
}());
```

> we wrap a function enclosure () and then I can call it, the reason in need to wrap the function enclosure is because the function itself without a name will return undefined, however when we wrap the function parenthesis we are essentially saying treat this whole thing as an expression which is evaluated immediately and doesn’t necessarily require a naming or assignment, now when we run the code and check the browser we will see that now the global namespace isn’t clutter with my variable. We could see that foo is undefined.

source treehouse workshop about basics module pattern in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 5 points using your class(like) example and the standard modular pattern.

**1. Multiple Instances:** Using class you can create multiple instances.

```
    function Human() {
        // private properties
        var _name = 'Bob'; // Each instance will gets a new private member copy

        // public for the created instance
        this.setName = function (name) { 
            _name = name;
        };

        this.getName = function () {
            return _name;
        };
        // setName() & getName() - can be moved to prototype for saving memory
    }

    // Instance - 1
    var h1 = new Human();
    h1.setName("John");
    console.log(h1.getName()); // John

   // Instance - 2
    var h2 = new Human();
    console.log(h2.getName()); // Bob  (NOTE: not John)
```

**2. Unique copy:** In the above example all the members in Human() class will get a new copy (Not shared) for each newly created instances.

Let's **convert** the above example into **Modular pattern:**

```
    var Human = (function() {
        // private properties
        var _name = 'Bob';

        // private
        setName = function (name) {
            _name = name;
        };

        // private
        getName = function () {
            return _name;
        };

        return { 
            setName: setName,
            getName: getName 
        };
    })();


    Human.setName('John');
    console.log(Human.getName()); // John

    Human.setName('Bob');
    console.log(Human.getName()); // Bob
```

3. In the above modular pattern example we **can't create any instance** like the above class example. Here the pattern allows you to set/get the values through **'Human'** in an organized way (not polluting the global scope).
4. Is it not possible to create a multiple instances in the modular pattern ?
   **Yes,** it is possible through constructor and prototype.

Let's add a constructor and prototype to the modular pattern:

```
        var Human = (function () {
        // private properties
        var _name = 'Bob'; // Shared across all the instance

        // private
        setName = function (name) {
            _name = name;
        };

        // private
        getName = function () {
            return _name;
        };

        // constructor
        var Human = function () { };

        // prototype
        Human.prototype = {
            constructor: Human,
            setName: setName,
            getName: getName
        };

        return Human;
    })();

    // Instance - 1
    var h1 = new Human();
    h1.setName("John");
    console.log(h1.getName()); // John

    // Instance - 2
    var h2 = new Human();
    console.log(h2.getName()); // John (NOTE: Not Bob bcos it uses the shared copy)
```

**5. Shared Copy:** From the above example you can see unlike a normal class, modular pattern above uses a **shared** private member copy for all the instances (In example point 1: Each instances will have it's **own** private members copy).