# Static classes in object literal

Tags: javascript

Right now I have the following static class in my application:

```
function Tools() { }
Tools.someFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
   // do something
};
```

But I'm changing the architecture of my js file to one object literal containing all classes, so I'd need something like:

```
var app = {
   someController: function() {

   };
   tools: function() ...
};
```

I actually have two questions:
- is this a good architecture in javascript to wrap all code in one big object?
- how can I append that static class to this literal?

Comment: both are good but I think second one is better because in it we can also have private functions and variables too. but both are good

Comment: First one can have private functions too..

Comment: Sidenote: OOP has no "static class" concept. There are static _members_ (methods or properties), not _classes_. Although a class containing only static members may be called static, however this is just a shortening term, not separate concept.

Comment: I don't agree that this question should be closed as opinion-based. Granted, it's not posed well. It contains two parts, one which might be considered a matter of opinion (should I wrap a bunch of code in an object?), but another which is not (how do I adorn functions specified as object methods with additional properties?). If the OP cares to narrow the question, it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dismiss the word *class* and use *prototype*. ECMA-Script 6 and above are introducing class-based object-oriented programming, but your code seems to be in the track of using prototypal-based inheritance system. Well, in fact, you're just creating objects using a *constructor function*.

Using the right terms is a good start to communicate with the community.

Secondly, in JavaScript there're no *static classes*. Functions are essential in JavaScript, and they're still objects. Like objects, functions are expandable and you can add properties unless you call `Object.preventExtensions` on them.

It's just that your constructor function has also a property holding a function.

If you want to hold that constructor function as part of your `app` object, add it as a regular property:

```
var app = {
    Tools: function() {}
};

app.Tools.someFunction = function() {

};
```

> is this a good architecture in javascript to wrap all code in one big
>   object?

Sure. But use *module pattern*. There're tons of articles about the topic on the net. You might want to check this other Q&A: [why module pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471349/why-module-pattern).

Comment: "your code is still using prototypal-based inheritance system" – where is it, I wonder. Otherwise, this is the answer I would recommend. :)

Comment: @Pavlo Haha, this is why I added the part **Well, in fact, you're just creating objects using a constructor function.**...

Comment: @Pavlo Check my edit...... I've reworded the sentence :D

Comment: "ECMA-Script 6 and above are introducing class-based object-oriented programming, but your code seems to be in the track of using prototypal-based inheritance system" – ES2015 Classes still use the prototype chain in the background ;)

Comment: *ECMA-Script 6 and above are introducing class-based object-oriented programming*. Wrong. They are introducing syntactic sugar for people that want to use class-based OOP with a more streamlined notation.

Comment: There's nothing whatsoever wrong with using the term "class" informally to mean a category of objects created using constructor functions, or the constructor used to create such objects.

Comment: @torazaburo I know (the syntactic sugar thing)

Comment: @torazaburo I prefer to call things by their exact term. They're not classes, thus, why should I call them *classes*? In JS it's better to call it just *object*...

Comment: @torazaburo I hate the discussion "something is done under the hoods". For those who're going to use class-based OOP shouldn't know it's syntactic sugar over prototype system unless they need to extend a non-class oriented code with class-oriented code, or just to continue coding JS without classes.......

Comment: @torazaburo In the other hand, the sentence "ECMA-Script6 introduces class-based object-oriented programming" isn't wrong. What has to do how it works under the hoods with the fact that **you're coding classes?**

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. JS has always had class-based object-oriented programming facilities, no matter what side of the argument about the semantics of using the words "class" or "object-oriented" as relates to JS one happens to stand on. It's just that using them required some syntactic somersaults. ES6 introduces no new features as regards classes. It just introduces new syntax.

Comment: @torazaburo actually this isn't true. JavaScript has been always an object oriented language which used prototypes to implement inheritance. Class based object oriented programming implies that you design classes. The fact that some js libraries already introduced the class semantics doesn't mean that vanilla JavaScript was already supporting the concept....

Comment: @torazaburo in fact, of you search in Google joopl github you'll find that I developed a class oriented library some time ago :D

Comment: even if anyone is using `class` keyword, we shouldn't be saying that those are classes. they are objects or prototypes. at best we should either say "object classes" or "prototype classes"

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good architecture to wrap all code in one big object?

Not really in this day and age. Of course this approach reduces your footprint on the global namespace to one single name, like `app`. But the same can be accomplished more easily using ES6 modules. It's remarkably easy to shift over. You can continue to write

```
function Tools() { }
Tools.someFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
   // do something
};
```

as you were before, but add

```
export default Tools;
```

Then, where you want to use this

```
import Tools from 'tools';
Tools.somefunction();
```

> how can I append that static class to this literal?

With ES6 modules you don't need to, but there are many patterns described in many questions here. Some examples:

IIFE:

```
var app = {
   someController: function() {
     var f = function() { };
     f.someProp = 42;
     return 42;
   }(),
```

Initializer:

```
var app = {
   someController: function() { },
   init: function() {
     this.someController.someProp = 42;
     return this;
   }
}.init();
```

Explicit assignment:

```
var app = {
   someController: function() { }
};
app.someController.someProp = 42;
```

None of these are very fun to read or write. They have sort of a 2012-era feel about them. Use ES6 modules to avoid this and go back to writing regular old code.