# Javascript using function directly and using function that is return from another function

Tags: javascript

Just out of pure curiosity I have seen codes like below

```
let GlobalActions = function () {

    let doSomething= function () {
        //Do Something
    };

    return {
        doSomething: function () {
            doSomething()
        }
    };
}();

GlobalActions.doSomething();
```

At first, I thought it was about scoping, maybe `var` declared variables from outside is not accessible from each functions inside after it has been initialized; however, that was not true.

Then it came to me thinking what is the advantage of doing the above instead of the below?

```
let GlobalActions = {

    doSomething: function () {
        //Do Something
    };

};

GlobalActions.doSomething();
```

Comment: This is the so-called "module pattern" that is used for private members, see [*Private Members in JavaScript*](https://crockford.com/javascript/private.html). There are [*many, many questions here already*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+module+pattern) (so this is likely a duplicate of some of them, maybe [*why module pattern?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471349/why-module-pattern)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like [The Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Essentially the returned object provides the "API" interface to the entire class. We can then choose what is exposed as public and what remains private. Eg.

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {

        var privateVar = "Ben Cherry",
            publicVar = "Hey there!";

        function privateFunction() {
            console.log( "Name:" + privateVar );
        }

        function publicSetName( strName ) {
            privateVar = strName;
        }

        function publicGetName() {
            privateFunction();
        }

        // Reveal public pointers to
        // private functions and properties

        return {
            setName: publicSetName,
            greeting: publicVar,
            getName: publicGetName
        };

    })();

myRevealingModule.setName( "Paul Kinlan" );
```

Comment: The "*publicVar*" isn't public, it's private. It's set by the privileged function *publicSetName*.

Comment: So it would exactly be same as using class?